# Is some thing wrong in this jquery code

Tags: jquery

Hi I have become total mad on finding problem with this code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#centCol").hide();
        var isBrand = $('#merchantOption', window.parent.document).val();
        var shopType = '<?php echo $this->shopDetail['shop_type']; ?>';
        if(isBrand == '1' && shopType != '4' && shopType != '10'){
            $('#menu').hide();
        }
    });
```

When I run this code it gives me an error

> $ is not defined $(document).ready(function() {

I have even tried by changing `$` with `jQuery` but nothing done. One thing that make me more mad that When this code is online there is no error...... Can any body tell me what the heck of this?

**UPDATED**

My head section looks like this

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>                <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"  href="/application_data/frontend/images/wlm-favicon.ico" />
    <link href="/application_data/css/structure-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/application_data/css/linkshare-color-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/application_data/css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/application_data/js/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/application_data/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/application_data/froomerce-frontend/js/common.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/application_data/ras-front/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/application_data/frontend/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/application_data/js/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>

        <link href="/application_data/frontend/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/application_data/frontend/css/skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        opacity = '0.7';
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".network").colorbox({width:"560px", height:"348px", iframe:true, opacity:opacity,onClosed:function(){ window.location.reload( false );}});
            $(".addWidget").colorbox({width:"860px", height:"890px", iframe:true, opacity:opacity,onClosed:function(){window.location='/widget/index/list';}});
            $(".postOnPage").colorbox({width:"525px", height:"700px", iframe:true, opacity:opacity});
            $(".embedcode").colorbox({width:"620px", height:"400px", iframe:true, opacity:opacity});
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Have you include jquery file in your page?

Comment: Do you have the jQuery library included in your page?

Comment: Is the script tag to load jQuery beneath the code you showed above?  If so, then jQuery just isn't available at the time you run  your code.

Comment: Please make sure jQuery included in your page

Comment: May be the relative path of your jquery.js you included and check the path.

Comment: @Kiran I have checked the path by taking page source... It is correct

Comment: Can you post the code for the head section of your page.

Comment: I have posted my head section after taking page source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Directory/jQuery.js"></script>
```

And have you tried including `jquery` and `jquery.min.js`

Make sure jQuery has its own separate script tag right above your own jQuery-dependent script

and chek if it is mentioned as `<script language="javascript">` and change to

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
```

I have changed your jquery path to this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

and tried with a small alert function and worked fine.May be your jquery file is corrupted.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>                <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"  href="/application_data/frontend/images/wlm-favicon.ico" />
    <link href="/application_data/css/structure-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/application_data/css/linkshare-color-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/application_data/css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/froomerce-frontend/js/common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/ras-front/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/frontend/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/js/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/application_data/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>

        <link href="/application_data/frontend/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/application_data/frontend/css/skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("a").click(function (event) {
                    alert("Thanks for visiting!");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: I have posted my head section after taking page source

Answer (score 2):

For all of you who say "have you included jQuery?", another situation which *could* break the thing is: Have you included jQuery *twice* by accident?

Comment: No its single time. But my page is also having jquery.ui and other jquery plugin files

Comment: I have posted my head section after taking page source

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the jquery framework on to your page..?

add this in to your head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if it is loading the jQuery file correctly (check the URL) then there may be a javascript error elsewhere on the page before your script above is being hit?

Comment: @Wayne, I don't think a Javascript error will prevent jQuery from at least loading.

Answer (score 1):

**Try** the code below and let me know

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" / >
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#centCol").hide();
        var isBrand = $('#merchantOption', window.parent.document).val();
        var shopType = '<?php echo $this->shopDetail['shop_type']; ?>';
        if(isBrand == '1' && shopType != '4' && shopType != '10'){
            $('#menu').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have posted my head section after taking page source

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the script tag for jQuery is included, try putting this right before the code above:

```
console.log(jQuery);
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(jQuery);
}, 2500);
```

Then load in Firefox, and open the Firebug console.  What do you see?

Comment: jQuery is not defined console.log(jQuery);

Comment: Do you see that twice?  If so, then for whatever reason, jQuery is not being loaded in your page when you run it locally.  Post the script tag that you use to load it.

Comment: no its single time. I have taken page source and see that there is jquery script tag. I clicked on link to check the source and it is correct

Comment: Without further information, I can't help.  If you see only one statement in the log, it means that something else is failing before the log statement in the setTimeout.  But if it is, you ought to see that in the console.  Next I think you should try what others have suggested, download a copy of jQuery and load it locally.

Comment: I have posted my head section after taking page source

Comment: The next step is to replace your script tag loading jQuery with  one that loads it from the Google CDN, as others have shown.  See if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you load JQuery from a Google CDN or other URL that is not accessible from your local machine, but is from your server.

Download JQuery from jquery.org, include it in your page, and try again!

Comment: I am loading jquery at the same page

Comment: I have posted my head section after taking page source

Comment: In Firefox or Chrome, you can see whether the file you want to load can indeed be loaded. So you can check if /application_data/js/jquery.min.js is or is not available on your local machine.